# Firestore security rules for specific document

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to apply the following situation :

- all authenticated users have read and write access to the database except for admin document.
- Admin document is accessible only for him for read and write.

My rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    //Functions
    function isAuthenticated(){
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function isAdministrator(){
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.name == resource.data.oid;
    }
    //Administrator Identity Check Point
    match /admin/identity {
        allow read, write: if isAdministrator();
        }
    //Allow Reads and Writes for All Authenticated Users
    match /{document=**}{
      allow read, write: if isAuthenticated();
    }
  }//databases/{database}/documents
}//cloud.firestore
```

Is there any way i can achieve this, actually when testing these rules, the tests succeed because only `isAuthenticated()` is being called because of the tag `/{document=**}`. I also tried `/{document!=/admin/identity}` but it does not work.

How can I write a security rule that follow this model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe on your default user rule you could check if the collection isn't admin, something like this:

```
//Allow Reads and Writes for All Authenticated Users
match /{collection}/{document=**}{
  allow read, write: if (isAuthenticated() && collection != "admin") || isAdministrator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since June 17, Firebase has provided new improvements to Firestore Security Rules.

[Firebase blog - 2020/06 - New Firestore Security Rules features](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features.html)

#### New Map methods

> We'll use `Map.get()` to get the `"roleToEdit"` field. If the document doesn't have the field, it will default to the `"admin"` role. Then we'll compare that to the role that's on the user's custom claims:

```js
allow update, delete: if resource.data.get("roleToEdit", "admin") == request.auth.token.role;
```

#### Local variables

> Say you're commonly checking that a user meets the same three conditions before granting access: that they're an owner of the product or an admin user.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function privilegedAccess(uid, product) {
      let adminDatabasePath = /databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(uid);
      let userDatabasePath = /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid);
      let ownerDatabasePath = /databases/$(database)/documents/$(product)/owner/$(uid);  

      let isOwnerOrAdmin = exists(adminDatabasePath) || exists(ownerDatabasePath);
      let meetsChallenge = get(userDatabasePath).data.get("passChallenge", false) == true;
      let meetsKarmaThreshold = get(userDatabasePath).get("karma", 1) > 5;
      return  isOwnerOrAdmin && meetsChallenge && meetsKarmaThreshold;
    }

    match /products/{product} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if privilegedAccess();
    }

    match /categories/{category} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if privilegedAccess();
    }

    match /brands/{brand} {
      allow read, write: if privilegedAccess();
    }
  }
}
```

The same conditions grant access to write to documents in the three different collections.

#### Ternary operator

> This is the first time we've introduced an `if/else` control flow, and we hope it will make rules smoother and more powerful.

Here's an example of using a ternary operator to specify complex conditions for a write.

A user can update a document in two cases: first, if they're an admin user, they need to either set the field `overrideReason` or `approvedBy`. Second, if they're not an admin user, then the update must include all the required fields:

```js
allow update: if isAdminUser(request.auth.uid) ? 
  request.resource.data.keys().toSet().hasAny(["overrideReason", "approvedBy"]) :
  request.resource.data.keys().toSet().hasAll(["all", "the", "required", "fields"])
```

It was possible to express this before the ternary, but this is a much more concise expression. ;)